# Using Async Values in another function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am currently working with destructuring arrays in Javascript, I would like to access these variables in other functions but currently, I am struggling to figure out how I might go about this.

I've tried calling the function and then `console.log(thermostatArray)` -> I believe this returned pending promise

I've tried calling the function and awaiting it and then `console.log thermostatArray`.

dataFormat() is properly able to see log and use the array but heatCallCheck() is not and I am not seeing past the issue yet.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
var Excel = require("exceljs");
const index = require("../routes/index");
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

async function convertFile(workbook) {
  csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile("./uploads/uploadedFile.csv");
  await csvWorkbook.then(async function(csvWorkbook) {
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("sheet1");
    try {
      // await dataFormat(worksheet);
      await heatCallCheck(worksheet,)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile("./uploads/convertedFile.xlsx").then(() => {
      console.log("converted file written");
    });
  });
}


async function dataFormat(worksheet) {
  let thermostatArray = []
  await csvWorkbook.then(async function(worksheet) {
    const serialNum = worksheet.getCell("D1").value;
    const thermostatName = worksheet.getCell("D2").value;
    const startDate = worksheet.getCell("D3").value;
    const endDate = worksheet.getCell("D4").value;
    const thermostat = worksheet.eachRow({includeEmpty: true}, function(row,rowNumber){
      if (rowNumber > 6) {
      thermostatArray.push(row.values)
      }
    })
    console.log(`${thermostatArray[5]} Array Sample from dataFormat` )
    console.log(`${thermostatArray[6]} Array Sample from dataFormat` )
    return thermostatArray
})}


async function heatCallCheck(worksheet,thermostatArray) {
  let test = await dataFormat(worksheet).then(thermostatArray => {
    return thermostatArray[5]
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
  console.log(`${test} result `)
}
```

My expected results, in this case, would be that I would be able to see the 4th element in thermostat array using the heatCallCheck() function.

I figured I would be able to access it after the .then is called.

my understanding is that .then(thermostatArray =>

makes that array the return value.

Comment: You don't use `await` and `then` together.

Comment: `thermostatArray` is for sure not a promise, since you've defined it as just `[]`. It's unclear to me why you need the inner `async` function on the `csvWorkbook.then` at all - you don't use `await` anywhere within it. From the [`exceljs` docs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) it's unclear to me that `csvWorkbook` is a promise. Do you need to await it at all (not that doing so harms anything)?

Comment: @Adam you certainly _can_ use `await` and `then` together, though there's generally not really a good reason to do so. `await` is meant to replace `.then`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst - yes, of course you **can**, you can `await` anything - `const x = 10; await x;` - but it's illogical (99% of the time anyway) and only serves to confuse the bejesus out of the code.

Comment: i thought the idea was that you awaited then did the next step , dang

Comment: @JasonHarder you `await` a promise, and after that just do normal code. The idea is to get rid of the nested `.then` calls

Comment: also, how is the array blank if I've created a rule to push into it and I can log values ?

Comment: I guess I thought I had to await thermostatArray since the variable depended on the workbook being read & the worksheet

Comment: @JasonHarder - you aren't `return`ing anything from `heatCallCheck` - well, actually you are returning a resolved promise with a value of `undefined`

Comment: You're likely trying to consume the array before the values are in it (because it's asynchronous). Put another log right before you use the array. You'll likely see that the log for using the array occurs before the logs where you put the values in. Seems like you need to do some reading on promises.

Comment: You have terribly misunderstood async javascript. Watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrNQS8J67zc.

Comment: 0.0 without await csvWorkbook the rest of my code won't run as the file reads out of order. But I didn't need the rest of it...

Comment: @matthew it seems like I do because without await I get a cannot get cell of undefined when iterating through my worksheet - the file has to be read before I can do anything with it.

Comment: @JasonHarder change `csvWorkbook = workbook.csv.readFile("./uploads/uploadedFile.csv");` to `csvWorkbook = await workbook.csv.readFile("./uploads/uploadedFile.csv");` and then you can remove the `await` and the `.then` on the line below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
async function someFunction() {
   const myResultFromAPromise = await functionThatReturnsAPromise();
   // ....do some stuff
   return myResultFromAPromise;
}
```

OR

```
function someFunction() {
   return functionThatReturnsAPromise().then(function(myResultFromAPromise) {
      // ...do some stuff
      return myResultFromAPromise;
   });
}
```

but don't do both, it's just terribly confusing.

EDIT: as a commenter pointed out, you can await anything, but it's clear from your code that you're very confused about the point of `async/await`

Comment: One important debugging difference for those new to `async`/`await`: in the first example above, if the promise rejects an error will be thrown in `someFunction`, while in the second example if the promise rejects an error will be thrown in whatever function called `someFunction`.

Comment: I am aware this isn't even an answer, but it's far too long to be a comment and I was simply trying to steer the OP onto the track of trying to write `async/await` code properly. It would be doing the OP (not to mention some other dev who might be tasked with maintaining this code in the future) a disservice to debug their code the way it's written. It needs to be cleaned up first.

Comment: I just wanted to thank everyone for the feedback, I recently got some help from a  QA professional on my app and I think my development has been going in a much better (TDD) direction.